# C++ non-public helper classes and inline code

Tags: c++, class, inline, header-files, encapsulation

I have C++ code with a lot of small helper classes that are not part of the public interface, and some larger classes. I'm "hiding" the helper classes by forward declaring them in the header file, and putting their declaration in the source file. Is this good and common practice or are there better ways to hide helper classes?

One more complication is that the large public classes have getter/setter functions which I'd would like to be inlined, so their code has to go in the header file. However, this code makes explicit use of the helper classes, so I also would have to define them in the header file. But then, they would be part of the public interface. Is there a way to make encapsulation work in such a situation?

Comment: I would not worry so much about being inlined. I mean  are you calling these many thousands of times so that inlined makes a measurable difference in time?

Comment: It's hard to comment on code we cannot see. [Mcve] please, always.

Answer (score 2):

> and putting their declaration in the source file.

You mean their definition. You already put a declaration in the header.

> Is this good and common practice

Defining classes in another translation unit is a good and common way to hide it from other translation units.

> or are there better ways to hide helper classes?

If you also remove the declaration from the header, then the helper class would be even more private.

Another thing to consider is what kind if privacy you are looking for. One simple approach would be to add a comment signifying what class and functions are and are not part of the public interface.

What approach is better depends on conditions.

> functions which I'd would like to be inlined, so their code has to go in the header file. However, this code makes explicit use of the helper classes, so I also would have to define them in the header file.

Those are your two options. You need to decide whether you value compile time inlineability or privacy more. Note that modern tool chains support inline expansion at linking stage in which case the functions don't necessarily need to be defined inline to allow that optimisation.